# R comparison with two columns using %like%

Tags: r

I would like to perform a soft match, similar to the "like" statement in mysql in R between two columns for example

> **Number1**
>
> **X1**
>
> 12345
>
> 67890
>
> 24689
>
> 13579
>
> **Number2**
>
> **X2**
>
> 123455555
>
> 678900000
>
> 246890000
>
> 135790000

In the case of these two data tables, I would like the output to return a subset of the first data set where an entry in the first dataset is "like" an entry in the second dataset. I tried using the data.table function %like%

> like_test<- Number1[Number1$X1 %like% Number2$X2] but it seems I cannot do a column match using this method, I need to use a specific string.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: maybe you are looking for grep, if the string in X1 will be entirely matched in X2, something like lapply(x1, grep, x2, value=T)

Comment: Or maybe `agrep`.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: Feel free to try `sqldf` to use the like statement in sql.

you can do the following.

```
library(sqldf)

new <- sqldf("select number1 from X1 join X2 where number1 like number2")
```

**Option 2:** You can try grep as below. Note: I have switched the X1,X2 order.

```
grep(pattern = paste0(X1,collapse = "|"),x = X2,value = T)
```

**Option 3**: You can still use %like% as below. Note: I have switched the X1,X2 order.

```
library(data.table)
X2[X2 %like% paste0(X1,collapse = "|")]
```